# How to fix error "Please use whereHasMorph() for MorphTo relationships." when using search function of Laravel BackPack?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, polymorphic-relationship

I have a very simple One-to-Many polymorphic relationship as following.

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string

videos
    id - integer
    title - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

Below is how the relationship in the models looks like:

```php
    class Comment extends Model
    {
        public function commentable()
        {
            return $this->morphTo();
        }
    }

    class Post extends Model
    {
        public function comments()
        {
            return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
        }
    }

    class Video extends Model
    {
        public function comments()
        {
            return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
        }
    }
```

I use Laravel Backpack CRUD to manage `comments`. In the `CommentCrudController::setup()` function, I add columns as following:

```
public function setup() {

    // Standard CrudPanel Basic Information goes here...

    $this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => 'body',
        'label' => 'Comment',
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
        'label' => "Related Entity",
        'type' => "select", // Need to use type 'select' for property of related model.
        'name' => 'commentable_id ', 
        'entity' => 'commentable', // Function name, defining the polymorphic relationship.
        'attribute' => "title", // The column name of the related database table.
    ]);

}
```

With above configuration in the `CommentCrudController::setup()` function, I get a comments overview table as normal. But when I tried to search for something using Backpack search form, I've got the following error:

```
{
  message: "Please use whereHasMorph() for MorphTo relationships."
  trace: [
    {file: vendor/backpack/crud/src/PanelTraits/Search.php", line: 91}
  ]
}
```

I do understand that because it is a `One-To-Many` polymorphic relation with `morphTo()` function and in the `CommentCrudController::setup()` function I used `'type' => "select"` to add the `title` of the `"Related Entity"` as column, when trying to search for records `Laravel Backpack` will try to execute the following query inside the `trait Search::applySearchLogicForColumn()` function:

```
    if ($column['tableColumn']) {
        switch ($columnType) {
            // Skipped other cases here...

            case 'select':
            case 'select_multiple':
                $query->orWhereHas($column['entity'], function ($q) use ($column, $searchTerm) {
                    $q->where($column['attribute'], 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
                });
                break;

            // Skipped default case here...
        }
```

As the error said, `$query->orWhereHas()` should be changed to `$query->whereHasMorph()`. But changing this does not solve the problem. And I also want to be able to search in the `title` column of the related model.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution by overriding the following three functions in the `CommentCrudController`:

```
search()
applySearchTerm($searchTerm)
applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm)
```

In the `search()` function, I preserved everthing, since it has things to do with pagination, sorting etc. Except calling `$this->crud->applySearchTerm()` function. I changed it to call `$this->applySearchTerm()` which I also overrided in the `CommentCrudController`.

Because in my use case, this operation works with specific database tables and columns, I could override the `applySearchTerm($searchTerm)` function as following:

```
public function applySearchTerm($searchTerm)
{
    return $this->crud->query->where(function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
        $this->applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm);
    });
}
```

And the solution happens by overriding the `applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm)` function as following:

```
public function applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm) 
{
    $query->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
          ->orWhereHasMorph(
              'commentable',
              [
                   Post::class,
                   Video::class,
              ], 
              function (Builder $query) use ($searchTerm) {
                   $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
              }
          );
}
```

In case, you have another associated morph model with a different column name than `title` e.g.

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string

videos
    id - integer
    title - string

users
    id - integer
    full_name - string  // table 'users' with 'full_name' column where you also want to apply search term to.

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

You can override the `applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm)` function as following:

```
public function applySearchLogicForColumn($query, $searchTerm) 
{
    $query->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
          ->orWhereHasMorph(
              'commentable',
              [
                   Post::class,
                   Video::class,
              ], 
              function (Builder $query) use ($searchTerm) {
                   $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
              }
          )
          ->orWhereHasMorph(
              'commentable',
              [
                   User::class,
              ], 
              function (Builder $query) use ($searchTerm) {
                   $query->where('full_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
              }
          );
}
```

Comment: Wow - sorry to hear you've had such a difficult time making a morphable column searchable. I'll see what we can learn from your example and include it into v4, thanks a lot for sharing your solution! Also, at first glance it looks like you can do the same thing in a less invasive manner - instead of overwriting ```search()``` you can specify a custom search logic for just that column, when you set it up. That would be cleaner, I think: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-columns#custom-search-logic